# Python Autoclicker

Tags: python, python-3.x, automation

I made this super basic autoclicker using Python (v3.7) and the pynput (v1.7.3) library.

Are there any changes that you could recommend to make the code more efficient, faster, and overall better?

Here's the code:

```
from pynput.keyboard import Controller
import time


# Autoclicker Functionality
def AutoClick(inputClickKey, inputClickAmount, inputClickDelay):
    keyboard = Controller();

    clickAmount = 1;

    while clickAmount <= inputClickAmount:
        clickAmount += 1;

        keyboard.press(inputClickKey)
        keyboard.release(inputClickKey)

        time.sleep(inputClickDelay)

# User Input
KeyInput = input("Key to be autoclicked: ");
ClickAmountInput = int(input("Number of autoclicks (integer): "))
ClickDelayInput = int(input("Delay between each autoclick in seconds (integer): "))

# Code Execution
AutoClick(KeyInput, ClickAmountInput, ClickDelayInput);
```

and Here's the GitHub repository:

https://github.com/SannanOfficial/AutoClickPython

Any sort of critique or suggestion would be appreciated. :)

Comment: "Are there any changes that you could recommend to make the code more efficient, faster" conflicts with `time.sleep`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is fairly simple (which is good) and there isn't much to make it "more efficient" or "faster". There's only a couple of suggestions I have to clean it up and you'll end up with a textbook example of a nice and short Python script that does something useful :)

## Replace the loop

You are using a `while` loop to control your iterations, but you know beforehand how many times you want to run your code **and** you don't care about the iteration you are at, so you can replace that loop by a more idiomatic one:

```py
for _ in range(inputClickAmount):
    # ...
```

People reading this code understand that you want something to run for `inputClickAmount` times and that you don't care about the number of your iteration.

## PEP 8 naming conventions

[PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) is the style guide for Python that recommends that you use `snake_case` for your variables:

- `input_click_amount` instead of `inputClickAmount`;
- `auto_click` instead of `AutoClick`;
- etc.

Of course being consistent within your code is better than following PEP 8 in some places and not following it in other places, so if your code is part of a larger library, for example, you would want to follow the conventions of that library.
Otherwise, for your personal projects I can recommend that you use this convention, as it will help your code fit in within the community.

## Basic error handling

This is a possible direction of improvement, and depends on how robust you want your code to become.

At the end of your script you have a couple of `int(input())` usages, which raise `ValueError`s if the user (which I think is you?) types something other than a number. To make a more robust application you would probably want to do some input validation/error handling.
I suggest you follow a "EAFP" coding style – Easier to Ask Forgiveness than Permition – that is, try to do the conversion with `int(input())` and only if it fails, handle that, for example by saying something to the user:

```py
try:
    click_amount_input = int(input(" ... "))
except ValueError:
    print("The number of clicks should be an integer, defaulting to 1")
    click_amount_input = 1
```

(You can read more about the EAFP coding style, and its counterpart LBYL (Look Before You Leap) in [this article](https://mathspp.com/blog/pydonts/eafp-and-lbyl-coding-styles?utm_source=codereview)).

Comment: Thank you very much for the suggestions mate. They were useful and I will most certainly implement them.

Comment: +1 This is implicit in the suggested refactoring, but to make it more explicit: while you're refactoring the input, you may want to encapsulate them inside a method like `read_number(question, by_default=1)` so you avoid duplication.

Comment: @fabiofili2pi I see, that as well is a good suggestion and I'll try to implement it as well.

Answer (score 3):

Some of this is covered by @RGS; still:

- Rather than `press`/`release`, just call `tap`
- Do not maintain your own loop counter
- Drop the semicolons
- Follow snake_case naming conventions for variables and methods
- Add a main guard
- The delay should not be constrained to an integer, and should accept floats
- Add type hints
- you could stand to simplify your variable names a little
- The comments do not offer value and should be deleted

More broadly, the naming is confusing - with no other information, seeing the method name I would assume mouse clicks. This is not an auto-clicker; you could call it an auto-typer, auto-key or somesuch.

Also, as @Peilonrayz hinted at, you can't particularly improve the performance of something that is already explicitly rate-limited via `sleep()`. This whole program can be reduced to a single call to `Controller().type(...)` unless you actually really, *really* need inter-key delay.

Suggested, covering most of the above, without bothering to add more input validation:

```
from pynput.keyboard import Controller
from time import sleep


def auto_click(key: str, n_clicks: int, delay: float) -> None:
    keyboard = Controller()

    for _ in range(n_clicks):
        keyboard.tap(key)
        sleep(delay)


def main() -> None:
    key = input('Key to be auto-clicked: ')
    n_clicks = int(input('Number of auto-clicks: '))
    delay = float(input('Delay between clicks (floating-point seconds): '))
    auto_click(key, n_clicks, delay)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Great answer as well, I'll try to implement all the suggestions that I can. Thanks.