# "Python AutoClicker" Part 2

Tags: python, python-3.x, automation

I previously posted a question for codereview:

[Python Autoclicker](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/259824/python-autoclicker)

And I received some great feedback and changes to do in the code.

I have done many of the changes mentioned in the answers and here is the final code:

```
from pynput.keyboard import Controller
from time import sleep


def auto_click(key: str, n_clicks: int, delay: float):
    keyboard = Controller()

    for _ in range(n_clicks):
        keyboard.tap(key)
        sleep(delay)


def main():
    key = input("Key to be autopressed: ")

    try:
        n_clicks = int(input("Number of autopresses (integer): "))
    except ValueError:
        print("\n The number of autopresses should be an integer value, defaulting to 1. \n")
        n_clicks = 1

    try:
        delay = float(input("Delay between each autopress in seconds (integer/float): "))
    except ValueError:
        print("\n The delay between each autoclick should be an integer or a decimal value, defaulting to 1 (second). \n")
        delay = 1

    auto_click(key, n_clicks, delay)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

What is it that you think should be made better in this code? Any feedback and suggestions would be much appreciated.

Here's the github repo:

https://github.com/SannanOfficial/AutoKeyPython

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is generally fine. I suspect you are not doing enough validation (for
example, to forbid negative values or multi-character keys). Also, if you want
to expand your toolkit, you can think about eliminating the duplication in your
code by generalizing the input collection process.

Collecting user input involves a few common elements: an input prompt, a
function to convert the string to a value, a function to validate that value,
an error message in the event of bad input, and possibly some other stuff (max
allowed attempts, fallback/default value in the event of bad input). If we
focus on just the basics, we end up with a function along the lines of this
sketch:

```
def get_input(convert, validate, prompt, errmsg):
    while True:
        try:
            x = convert(input(prompt + ': '))
            if validate(x):
                return x
            else:
                print(errmsg)
        except ValueError:
            print(errmsg)
```

With that in hand, all of the algorithmic detail will reside in that single
function, and your `main()` will be little more than straightforward,
step-by-step orchestration code.

```
def main():
    key = get_input(
        str.strip,
        lambda s: len(s) == 1,
        'Key to be autopressed',
        'Invalid, must be single character',
    )
    n_clicks = get_input(
        int,
        lambda n: n > 0,
        'Number of autopresses',
        'Invalid, must be positive integer',
    )
    delay = get_input(
        float,
        lambda n: n > 0,
        'Delay between autopresses',
        'Invalid, must be positive float',
    )
    auto_click(key, n_clicks, delay)
```

As shown in that sketch, I would also encourage you to favor a more compact
style in messages to users. Brevity usually scales better across a variety of
contexts than verbosity: it's easier to maintain; it's easier to make
consistent across an entire application; and most people don't appreciate
having to slog through long messages when an equally clear short one
is possible.

Finally, you might also consider whether `input()` is the best
mechanism to get this information from the user. In my experience,
it is almost always preferable to take such values from the
command-line, either from `sys.argv` directly or, more commonly,
using a library like [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html). The advantages
to this approach are numerous.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer, mate. All of your suggestions make sense to me and I'll try to implement all of them If I can.

Answer (score 2):

If `n_clicks` and `delay` have default values, you can put them directly in the signature of your `auto_click` function so that you can call it with the `key` parameter only. (I would also rename rename `n_clicks` to `clicks`, but that's a personal preference really:))

```py
def auto_click(key: str, n_clicks: int = 1, delay: float = 1):
    keyboard = Controller()
    for _ in range(n_clicks):
        keyboard.tap(key)
        sleep(delay)
```

As @FMc mentionned, we don't usually use `input()` to take user input, but rather execute the program from the command line. There is an amazing library made by Google called `fire` (`pip install fire`) that generates the necessary code for you based on your function's signature:

```py
import fire
from time import sleep
from pynput.keyboard import Controller


def auto_click(key: str, n_clicks: int = 1, delay: float = 1):
    keyboard = Controller()
    for _ in range(n_clicks):
        keyboard.tap(key)
        sleep(delay)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    fire.Fire(auto_click)
```

Now you can call your script from the command line like so:

```
python myscript.py --key A --n_clicks 5 --delay 1
```

Or, since you have default parameters:

```
python myscript.py --key A
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'll try to implement whatever I can that you suggested.